# How should I inform a client about increased uncertainty in case of health issues?

Tags: communication

I'm having some trouble during last few weeks, and it's happening along a freelance project I took before. Moreover, it's not me who has problem but my daughter. After the last visit to doctor we're both obliged to stay at home for at least two extra weeks. The project is on fire, the deadline is coming. I informed my client about what is going to happen and already got Terms and Conditions edited and accepted. What should I do now to not look like a slacker or a person who is incapable of time management?

Answer (score 6):

First off, communication is key; you state you already told them about it, just re-affirm with them. When you do, have your exit plan ready.

> I'm sorry I can't continue with the project as scheduled; given the events leading up this this, I can't work on it as much as promised. I can recommend Mr X of Super Y Agency to help you accomplish the remaining goals, and I will email you all the work I have so far.

Something short and simple, but giving the client an actionable item will help. You are offering your alternative solution, so they are now responsible for getting the project done.

If you are thinking of continuing with the project, you need to decide if it's worthwhile, given whatever the situation is. I assume medical - this can take a large toll on a family. If it's a short hiccup, you may be safe just simply delaying the project for the couple weeks. However, you still need to be prepared to get out *just in case* you need to, and you don't want your client to feel like you're just running away and burning the bridges.